# Upload videos on vimeo from youtube or other sites

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, vimeo-api

I am just developing the application where i want to upload the videos to vimeo account using pull request.I checked the vimeo api and integrated in my project. My problem is the video is not ruuning on vimeo. I am pulling the video from youtube. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var data = {
    "upload" : {
        "approach" : "pull",
        "link" : "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZUSPD9zOyJs"
    }
}


    $.ajax({
        url : "https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos",
          cache:false,
          dataType : "json",
        headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4',
        'Authorization': 'bearer xxxxxxxxx',
        'Content-Type':'application/json'   
         },

        type : 'POST',
        data:JSON.stringify(data),
        success : function(response) {  
                console.log(response)

        },

    });

})
```

Comment: Unrelated but, won't this affect the video quality quite a lot? You download a compressed video and upload it to Vimeo that compresses it even more.

Comment: I just want to pull the videos for testing purpose..can this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The upload.link value you provide must be a direct link to a video file resource, not a web page.

For example, you provided:

`"upload": {"link":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZUSPD9zOyJs"}`

You'll want to use a direct link to a video file like this:

`"upload": {"link":"http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/big_buck_bunny_480p_surround-fix.avi"}`

(this is a link to an SD version of the open source film [Big Buck Bunny](http://bbb3d.renderfarming.net/download.html), commonly used for testing)

Vimeo API pull upload documentation is found here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#using-the-pull-approach